# JavaScript, getting value of a td with id name

Tags: javascript

Originally I was using input with an id and grabbing it's value with getElementById. Currently, I'm playing with `<td>`s. How can I grab the values of the `<td>`?

Originally I used:

```
<input id="hello">
document.getElementById("hello").value;
```

Now I want to get value of `<td>`, but I don't know how;

```
<td id="test">Chicken</td>
<td>Cow</td>
```

**Edit:** What's the difference between `textContent`, `innerHTML`, and `innerText`?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To get the text content

```
document.getElementById ( "tdid" ).innerText
```

or

```
document.getElementById ( "tdid" ).textContent

var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "tdid" );
var tdText = tdElem.innerText | tdElem.textContent;
```

If you can use jQuery then you can use

```
$("#tdid").text();
```

To get the HTML content

```
var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "tdid" );
var tdText = tdElem.innerHTML;
```

in jQuery

```
$("#tdid").html();
```

Comment: Interesting. Under which conditions is `textContent` the better choice?

Comment: innerText isn't supported in FF.

Comment: @Pekka웃 `innerText` returns a version of the text similar to [what would show](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) on screen (including new lines and spacing).  `textContent` gets exactly what is between the start and end tag (including tabs and spaces) with all child tags removed (though their text is also included).  In general, you should always use `textContent` to prevent compatibility issues with FF.

Answer (score 10):

use the

```
innerHTML
```

property and access the `td` using `getElementById()` as always.

Answer (score 9):

Again with getElementById, but instead .value, use .innerText

```
<td id="test">Chicken</td>
document.getElementById('test').innerText; //the value of this will be 'Chicken'
```

Comment: Work like a charm

Answer (score 3):

If by 'td value' you mean text inside of td, then:

```
document.getElementById('td-id').innerHTML
```

Comment: Is it supposed to have a hyphen?

Comment: @Doug No, it's just an example. You need to put your ID in there.

Answer (score 3):

For input you must have used `value` to grab its text but for td, you should use `innerHTML` to get its html/value. Example:

```
alert(document.getElementById("td_id_here").innerHTML);
```

To get its text though, use:

```
alert(document.getElementById("td_id_here").innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `getElementbyId('ID_OF_ID').innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

`.innerText` doesnt work in Firefox.

`.innerHTML` works in both the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

if i click table name its shown all fields about table. i did table field to show. but i need to know click function.

My Code:

```
$sql = "SHOW tables from database_name where tables_in_databasename not like '%tablename' and tables_in_databasename not like '%tablename%'";


$result=mysqli_query($cons,$sql);

$count = 0;

$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $count++;

    $tbody_txt .= '<tr>';

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if($count  == '1') {
            $thead_txt .='<td>'.$key.'</td>';
        }
        $tbody_txt .='<td>'.$value.'</td>';


        $array[$key][] = $value;
    }
}?>
```