# How to check value of table td?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create mine field game. "I am very new to Js".

What I have done so far:

```
var level = prompt("Choose Level: easy, medium, hard");
if (level === "easy") {
    level = 3;
} else if (level === "medium") {
    level = 6;
} else if (level === "hard") {
    level = 9;
}
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    document.write("<br/>");
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        if (j < level) {
            j = "mined";
        } else {
            j = "clear";
        }
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(j + " ");
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
}
tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
body.appendChild(tbl);
tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
```

So I create here 2d table and enter 2 random values in rows and columns (mined or clear).

Where I am stuck is:

Check if td = mined it dies otherwise open the box(td) etc.

How do I assign **value** of td? I mean how can I check which value(mined/clear) there is in the td which is clicked?

Ps: Please don't write the whole code:) just show me the track please:)

Thnx for the answers!

Ok! I came  this far.. But if I click on row it gives sometimes clear even if I click on mined row or vice versa!

```
  // create the table
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
  tbl.setAttribute('id','myTable');
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");


  //Create 2d table with mined/clear
  for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
     {
   var row = document.createElement("tr");
    document.write("<br/>" );

for(var x=1;x<=10;x++)
{
 var j=Math.floor(Math.random()*12+1);

 if(j<level)
 {
 j = "mined";
 }
 else{
 j = "clear";
 }
 var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(j + "");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);

}
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
     }
     tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
      body.appendChild(tbl);
     tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");


  //Check which row is clicked

     window.onload = addRowHandlers;

function addRowHandlers() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler = 
        function(row) 
        {
            return function() { 
                 var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                 var id = cell.innerHTML;
              if(id === "mined")
              {
              alert("You died");
              }else
              {
              alert("clear");
              }
              };
        }

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
           }
           }
```

I think I do something wrong with giving the table id "myTable"..

Can you see it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe are you looking for this?
[Node.textContent Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Answer (score 1):

So, the idea would be:

1. assign a click event to each td cell:

   `td.addEventListener('click', mycallback, false);`
2. in the event handler (callback), check the content of the td:

   `function mycallback(e) { /*e.target is the td; check td.innerText;*/ }`

*Pedagogic resources:*

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Ftd
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener
- [JavaScript, getting value of a td with id name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310145/javascript-getting-value-of-a-td-with-id-name)