# Why is the value of a table cell returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Jquery:**

```
$datasearch.append('<tr>'
    +'<td class="edit-btn" id='+"tid"+' onClick='+"pic()"+'  value='+"hhh"+'></td>'+
    +'</tr>');
```

**function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pic() {
    var x = document.getElementById("tid").value;
    alert(x);
 }
</script>
```

> Error: alert Undefined

Comment: `id='+"tid"+'`  <-- ????? Not to mention that `td` elements don't have a `value` property/attribute, they have `.textContent` and `.innerHTML`. I think you should start by cleaning up your code to make it valid.

Comment: There's not much description here, nor really a good way of reproducing this. Can you please create a [mre]? You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make sure it runs. Note that concatenating a string to add an event handler is a pretty old method; you could just use jQuery's [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method to do it instead...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript, getting value of a td with id name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310145/javascript-getting-value-of-a-td-with-id-name)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i want to get value="" property, example which you have given is not returning value. can you please help how to fetch only value.

Comment: As mentioned, there isn't anything in the question. Please [edit] your question to make it clear what exactly your question is. As for the answer, a hint: `getAttribute`.

Comment: Why does this have the `jquery` tag if you're using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: What is the exact error message? `alert Undefined` doesn't look an error I've seen.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'data' attribute instead 'value'

```
$datasearch.append(
`<tr>
   <td class="edit-btn" id="tid" data="hhh">hhh</td> 
</tr>`);
```

Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(()=> {
    $('body').on('click', '#tid', function() {
      let $this = $(this);
      let x = $this.data() || $this.attr('data');
      alert(x);
    }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You've added template literals, arrow functions, unnecessary short-circuited assignments, and changed event binding, while adding an event namespace. You've also corrected the invalid HTML - -- All without any explanation. This may work, but at Stack Overflow, we want to have people understand our answers.